# how to read data from text file and display it over the Memo fields?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a text file called profile.txt that contains data like this

```
1   Sharon   Jasper   Male
2   Steven   John   Male
3   Mary   Hill   Female
```

In my form there have one text box called edtId and find button (btnFind),and a memo field.While clicking the find button corresponding data should display on the memo. 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The following proc will select a string inside a memo.
In order to load a text file into a memo simply call Memo1.LoadFromFile(filepath);

```
procedure TForm1.btnFindClick(Sender: TObject);
var i,l,p: integer;
begin
  l := Length(edtId.Text);
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do begin
    p := Pos(edtId.Text,Memo1.Text);
    if p <> 0 then begin
      Memo1.SetFocus;
      Memo1.SelStart := p-1;
      Memo1.SelLength := l;
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

if you need to display only one line of text, simply save the line index inside that procedure and delete all other lines using Memo1.Lines.Delete(index).

Comment: This code is very inefficient. For one thing, the loop is useless. If you use a loop, it needs to use `Memo1.Lines[i]` instead of `Memo1.Text`, but then you have to change how `Memo1.SelStart` is assigned because `p` would be the wrong value. A simpler solution is to get rid of the loop completely. Even better, switch to a `TRichEdit` and use its `FindText()` method instead of `Pos()`.

Comment: you are right but this code only finds a substring (the id in this case) and select it. There are no other way to find a substring in a TMemo. if he's looking for find a "record" in a memo, obviously he needs to use Memo1.Lines[i] (and it works only if [e.g.] edtId 1 is at line 1). I agree with you to switch to TRichEdit. But I think manage records in a Memo is the worst way to do it, it's better to use a database or at least an array of records.

Comment: My earlier comments still stand. If you are going to loop through the `Memo` one line at a time then do not use the `Text` property at all. Otherwise, use TRichEdit and utilize its built-in searching functionalty.